# Internet Explorer - Select tab in Multipage

Tags: html, excel, vba, authentication, internet-explorer

**<sub>Background:</sub>**

For a project I'm trying to control a page and it's elements. I'm very new to controling webpages through VBA but managed to use logon-credentials, click some intermediate windows and controls to finally get into the main page of interest: Ultimo. Unfortunately I cannot share the URL and logon credentials so I'm sorry for only pasting some `HTML` and a massive screenshot.

---

**<sub>Problem:</sub>**

After logon and navigating to this specific menu I got stuck on what appears a multitab frame. Below is the `HTML` that I got through `.document.body.innerHTML`

```html
<div class="c-viewport c-container c-component" id="viewport">
   <div class="c-maincontainer c-container c-component l-vbox" id="maincontainer">
      <div class="maintoolbar c-maintoolbar c-toolbar c-container c-component l-hbox" id="maintoolbar" style="height: 50px; line-height: 50px;">
         <div class="mainmenuicon c-container c-component l-flow" id="container14" style="width: 32px;"><button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-menu1" id="button17" type="button"></button></div>
         <div class="logo clickable c-container c-component l-flow" id="container20"><img title="Logo" class="c-image c-component" id="image23" src="ultimo.framework.web/assets/images/system/ultimo-logo-small.png"></div>
         <div class="history c-history c-toolbar c-container c-component l-hbox" id="history" style="height: 50px; line-height: 50px;">
            <button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-history-previous" id="button28" type="button"></button><button tabindex="-1" disabled="" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-history-next" id="button31" type="button"></button>
            <div class="c-menubutton c-container c-component l-flow" id="menubutton34"><button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-arrow-dropdown" id="button37" style="height: 100%;" type="button"></button></div>
         </div>
         <span class="c-separator c-component" id="separator64"></span><button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-home" id="button67" type="button"></button><span class="c-template c-component l-template" id="header"><span class="breadcrumbs"><span class="icon icon-breadcrumb-item-separator"></span><span>Decompositie per niveau</span><span class="icon icon-breadcrumb-item-separator"></span><span>Objecten</span></span>
         </span>
         <div class="c-fill c-component" id="fill72" style="flex:1 1 1px;"></div>
         <div class="c-menubutton c-container c-component l-flow" id="settingsMenu"><button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-gear" id="button77" style="height: 100%;" type="button"></button></div>
         <div class="c-menubutton c-container c-component l-flow" id="recordPackage" style="display: none;"></div>
         <button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-search" id="search" type="button"></button>
         <div class="c-menubutton c-container c-component l-flow" id="menuhelp"><button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-help" id="button156" style="height: 100%;" type="button"></button></div>
         <button tabindex="-1" class="c-badgebutton c-button c-component c-badgebutton-appearance-icon c-badgebutton-large icon icon-notification" id="notifications" type="button"></button><span class="c-separator c-component" id="separator199" style="display: none;"></span><span class="c-template c-component l-template" id="template202" style="display: none;"><span class="dtap dtap-production">Production</span>
         </span><span class="c-separator c-component" id="separator205"></span><span class="welcome literal c-literal c-component" id="literal208">here was my username</span><span class="c-separator c-component" id="separator211"></span><button tabindex="-1" class="c-button c-component c-button-appearance-icon c-button-large icon icon-logout" id="button214" type="button"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="c-container c-component l-hbox" id="container217" style="left: 0px; top: 50px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;">
         <div class="c-mainmenubar c-container c-component l-flow" id="mainmenubar224" style="display: none;">
            <div title="Mijn Ultimo" class="item" data-index="0"><i class="app-icon-user"></i></div>
            <div title="Werkprocessen" class="item" data-index="1"><i class="app-icon-infra"></i></div>
            <div title="Beheer en onderhoud" class="item" data-index="2"><i class="app-icon-selfservice-requestrebuilding"></i></div>
            <div title="Industriele automatisering" class="item" data-index="3"><i class="app-icon-processfunction-configuration"></i></div>
            <div title="De balie registraties" class="item" data-index="4"><i class="app-icon-job-fleet"></i></div>
            <div title="Verkenners" class="item" data-index="5"><i class="app-icon-module-explorers"></i></div>
            <div title="Decompositie per niveau" class="item" data-index="6"><i class="app-icon-processfunction-object"></i></div>
            <div title="Organisatie" class="item" data-index="7"><i class="app-icon-building"></i></div>
            <div title="Contracten" class="item" data-index="8"><i class="app-icon-servicecontract-infra"></i></div>
            <div title="Programmering" class="item" data-index="9"><i class="app-icon-cost"></i></div>
            <div title="Arbeidsmiddelen" class="item" data-index="10"><i class="app-icon-inspection"></i></div>
            <div title="Functioneelbeheer" class="item" data-index="11"><i class="app-icon-job-servicerequest"></i></div>
            <div title="Geo-informatie" class="item" data-index="12"><i class="app-icon-address"></i></div>
            <div title="Gebouw" class="item" data-index="13"><i class="app-icon-building-standard"></i></div>
            <div title="Inkoop" class="item" data-index="14"><i class="app-icon-purchase"></i></div>
            <div title="Magazijn" class="item" data-index="15"><i class="app-icon-warehouse-standard"></i></div>
            <div title="HSE" class="item" data-index="16"><i class="app-icon-hse"></i></div>
            <div title="FIT" class="item" data-index="17"><i class="app-icon-pmworkorder"></i></div>
            <div title="Algemeen" class="item" data-index="18"><i class="app-icon-general"></i></div>
            <div title="Stamgegevens" class="item" data-index="19"><i class="app-icon-basic"></i></div>
            <div title="Statische overzichten " class="item" data-index="20"><i class="app-icon-report"></i></div>
            <div title="Instellingen" class="item" data-index="21"><i class="app-icon-settings"></i></div>
            <div title="TD" class="item" data-index="22"><i class="app-icon-technicalservice"></i></div>
         </div>
         <div tabindex="0" class="c-mainmenu c-menu c-treepanel c-panel c-container c-component l-vbox has-arrows" id="mainmenu">
            <div class="c-panelheader c-toolbar c-container c-component l-hbox" id="panelheader229" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="panelbody c-container c-component l-flow" id="container241">
               <table class="treenode is-toplevel is-expanded is-hidden">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-toplevel is-expanded">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Decompositie per niveau">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-processfunction-object"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner">Decompositie per niveau</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Hoofdsysteem">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/24d7a953-c8a4-4b8a-cc91-28d551c8c033">Hoofdsysteem</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Systeem">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/052769b9-757c-4a3c-d7da-6cd2f20c389e">Systeem</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Systeemdeel">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/a129239c-58d2-4d9d-8a95-c543aff824f2">Systeemdeel</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Complexen">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/58ab5a6e-e1ad-41d2-a992-3ceab120644a">Complexen</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf is-selected is-highlight">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Objecten">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/fefbf433-378d-4bd4-ad8d-e395c22100cf">Objecten</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Installaties">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/2fd711d4-f0d8-41aa-c3b8-96d204d756ee">Installaties</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Elementen">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/7aa389ad-73ce-4f1d-b7c1-fe67ce7e5907">Elementen</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Onderdelen">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/f88c0a48-c29a-4e14-96c4-feb20c9e12ba">Onderdelen</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Bouwdelen">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/8c24ae05-07a0-4446-a625-292dcb2359a1">Bouwdelen</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <table class="treenode is-leaf">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr title="Componenten">
                        <td class="line pad"><i class="app-icon-"></i></td>
                        <td class="line first"></td>
                        <td class="line"></td>
                        <td class="line">
                           <div class="toggleimage"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inner"><a tabindex="-1" href="main.aspx#screen/5663968c-ede6-4045-8d90-7274ed812cb6">Componenten</a></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
```

This helped me navigate the menu on the left into "Decompositie per niveau" > "Objecten" using code like:

```
For Each oHTML_Element In .document.getElementsByTagName("td")
    If oHTML_Element.innerHTML = "Decompositie per niveau" Then oHTML_Element.Click
Next

For Each oHTML_Element In .document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If oHTML_Element.innerHTML = "Objecten" Then oHTML_Element.Click
Next
```

Whereas the above succesfully opens the problematic multitab view, upon inspecting the element (higlighted tab) I don't see/recognize my `HTML` anymore. Looking at the code I gave `IsObject(.document.getElementById("IdInputTab"))` a try but this return `FALSE`. I highlighted what I think I should be refering to in below screenshot. When the correct tab is selected, the "title" changes to "clsTabPage is-selected". There is one other tab (right below the highlighted one), which then is hidden and shows a title that is empty.

[image]

[image]

---

**<sub>Question:</sub>**

I tried multiple things found both:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712520/9758194): Trying to change classname
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902089/9758194): Trying to use CSS selector

But to no avail. Where I could follow the logic of finding the other elements by either ID/Name, I fail to understand how to "click" the correct tab (and it's underlaying elements) in this window.

---

**EDIT** Based on comments:

The following (when added to working steps above) for example would return error 424 Object required:

```
Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30")
Range("C1").Value = .document.querySelector("[id='iframe258']").contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

Or:

```
Debug.Print IsObject(.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("IdInputTab"))
```

will return `False`

I did however recieve an `HTML` innertext through: `.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.body.innerHTML`. Since the body of the question doesn't support anymore characters (and I want to be complete as possible). Hereby a [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/899ce3cab196c1d7bdea7866042cb33c20200311095841/ed0749) to a notepad file.

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing I did notice is this element appears to be in an iFrame. You'll need to adjust your selector to reach into that frame first. E.g. `IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.` should give you the document of the first iFrame

Comment: @RyanWildry, `.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.body.innerHTML` has given me the `HTML` code indeed. I guess `.document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).getElementsbyID(....` could work then? Not sure how this would work now. Thanks for the pointer though =)

Comment: IIRC,  it'd be something like `.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyID("MyID")`. Keep in mind there is no `getElementsbyID`, only the `getElementbyID` method. ID's are unique to a document, so it returns a single element opposed to a collection.

Comment: You might need to add an extra delay when loading the page as you aren't just waiting for the top level page to load, but also the iFrame. Try just returning the `.contentDocument` object and having a look around, or writing the `HTML` to an HTML object to browse

Comment: What about use `Debug.Print ieA.document.querySelector("[id='iframe258']").contentDocument.getElementById("IdInputTab").innerHTML`? Will it give you the html code of the `<div>`? I made a test with some simplifed html and it can work. If not working for you, what is the error thrown?

Comment: Have you set the `ieA` in your code? Like `Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. If you can get the html code form `Debug.Print ieA.document.querySelector("[id='iframe258']").contentDocument.body.innerHTML`, then it's strange you can't get the elements inside. Maybe the iframe is not fully load, you need to add a delay to wait it to load as Ryan said.

Comment: Is there any update about this thread? Have you found the solution or any workaround of the issue? If you have any other issues, feel free to update the thread and I'll take a look.

Comment: @RyanWildry, unfortunately no luck so far. As I managed to pull `.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.body.innerHTML` I wasn't able to manouvre anywhere (maybe I just don't know how). I have updated the question with the HTML that I got throught your suggestion. Maybe that helps?

Comment: It seems that the link to the notepad file is broken. It shows "This upload does not exist". Besides, from the screenshot, it seems that the iframe id will change every time. Then we can't use id to get the iframe. I'll continue to research and let you know if I have any result.

Comment: @YuZhou, does the updated link work? Thank you for thinking along. It's appreciated =)

Comment: @qharr. Do you mind if I tag you? I am at the ferge of throwing the towel on my issue and I seen you mastering the internet automation before (you helped me on several occasions). If you have any idea on how to control the `iFrame` please let me know.

Comment: I wasn't in this thread so never got the ping I'm afraid. Came across it by chance today.

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with the code you providing in the link like this:

**Main.html：**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe258" name="IdIframe" src="Iframe.html" width="1200" height="800"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Iframe.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
...the code you providing in the link...
</body>
</html>
```

**VBA code:**

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim url As String

    url = "http://your_domain/Main.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url
    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document
    Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set iframeDoc = doc.frames("IdIframe").document
    If iframeDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "IFrame with name 'IdIframe' was not found."
        ie.Quit
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Debug.Print IsObject(iframeDoc.getElementById("IdInputTab"))
End Sub
```

I can get `True` for `Debug.Print IsObject(iframeDoc.getElementById("IdInputTab"))`, you could check [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL1iA.gif) and refer to my sample.

**Update:**

I made example with your html code, if you mean click this `<div>` : 
[image]

But I didn't see any function which will be triggered in `div` so I have no idea what will happen when I click the `div`. I add `onclick="alert('aaa')"` in that `div` and the function will be triggered by the following code:

```
iframeDoc.getElementsByClassName("clsScrollContainer")(0).getElementsByClassName("clsTab")(0).Click
```

Comment: This get me `TRUE`. Very nice Yu Zhou. Now I wish to actually click the right tab, which is problematic. Nothing happens when I use `iframeDoc.getElementById("IdInputTab").Click`. It seems like the tabs themselves have no `ID`. Is that possible?

Comment: [here](https://imgur.com/MWDYdVB) you can see the element I need to `Click` to get to the right tab. But it doesn't seem to have an ID... Which is strange to me since what I thought would be the correct ID is below "IDinputTab".

Comment: It does click something, but no idea what. There is no physical change on the screen. The tab is not getting selected. Does this have to do with events? I'm at a loss here. Thanks for your tremendous help though. I'll upvote since you took me further than I could get on my own.

Comment: I also noticed that when you click the top tab, it changes to `clsTab Is-Selected`, and then the bottum one would be `clsTab`. This switches when you manually click the bottum tab.

Comment: Yes, so there must be some scripts to control this. Add a `is-selected` class when click and remove the `is-selected` class if it lose focus, something like this. Maybe you can research the scripts of the website to see how it control the tabs and change the classes. I think it will be helpful for your vba automation.

Comment: There seem to be some `event` driven proces. [Here](https://imgur.com/bdF9i94) another picture. If you see more to the bottum. There is an event button behind the first tab, and none behind the second. I think I'll have to throw the towel here.

Comment: What about this: add the `is-selected` style to it instead of clicking it in vba? Then it will also looks like clicked. Just a guess, I'll try to research it tomorrow.

Comment: `iframeDoc.getElementsByClassName("clsScrollContainer")(0).getElementsByClassName("clsTab")(0).Select` is accepted code but physically doesn't change anythin on the screen.

Comment: I'm sorry it's difficult for me to investigate more as the html structure of the page is case specific. The only thing I can suggest for now is that you can check if you have located the right element of the clickable tab. If you need to click the sub element of the `<div>` or if you need to click another "clsScrollContainer" element as there're two elements using this class, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight nonetheless. I managed to atleast assing values to the right tab without selecting it. Now I'm struggling to operate click/select events on that tab. If I do happen to open a new question I'll get back to you here OK?

Comment: Thanks for your trust. You can open a new thread or come back to me any time if you have further questions.